# SSRS scale-out deployment, adding third AG replica

Tags: sql-server-2019, ssrs-2019

We have two SQL Server 2019 Enterprise instances each running on Windows Server 2022 Standard (let’s call them DB01 and DB02).  We have two SSRS servers (RS01 and RS02) each running SSRS 2019. They’re in a scale-out deployment, with ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB in a dedicated AlwaysOn Availability Group. All these servers are on the same subnet.

The SSRS AG is configured for automatic failover and synchronous commit with a readable secondary.  Secondary is preferred for backups.

For additional HA and an improved backup process, we recently added a third SQL Server instance (same version) to the cluster.  The intent is to use this for backups, with our off-site backup solution pulling the SQL native backup files from this server.  I added this replica to the SSRS AG with manual failover, asynchronous commit, and a backup priority of 75 (default is 50).  An hour later, both SSRS servers were unavailable (users got the Circle of Despair) and the ReportingServicesService logs had these errors:

> library!WindowsService_6!1904!03/18/2024-15:28:52:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;

> dbpolling!WindowsService_6!1904!03/18/2024-15:28:52:: e ERROR: PollingFunction: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.

> library!ReportServer_0-7!148!03/18/2024-15:29:40:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RunningJobsDb.GetMyRunningJobs(JobTypeEnum runningJobType)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;

The database was online and accessible, AG dashboard showed green on all three replicas, nothing was blocking SSRS requests.  In my searches through Microsoft documents, there’s been no indication that scaling out the SSRS database to more than two replicas would cause problems.  All the non-Microsoft sources I’ve seen only mention two replicas. I’m not sure if this outage was caused by my adding the third replica or that was a coincidence.

TLDR: will SSRS work with a scale out to three AG replicas? What (if any) are recommended settings? Are there any gotchas I should be aware of?